# Trying to Build Tails OS from a Debian10 VM in Virtual, but getting KVM error

Tags: linux, debian, tails-os

I added LINUX as a tag because I dont know if the KVM error is OS based, or if it is an error with general linux I am trying to overcome.

Situation:  Tails is a privacy based Linux Operating system. [Link to Build Process](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/build/)  I do not have dedicated Linux hardware, so I was thinking to use Virtualization to run Debian 10 with Virtualbox.

Goal:  I want to build the TAILS OS as an installable ISO myself.

Givens:
  Access to Windows and Mac machines running Debian 10 x64 on Virtual Box
  Followed the build work flow.
My current specs for a test:A VM (via virtual box) on my machine running DEBIAN 10 by a 64 bit install iso: *debian-10.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso*, with a data dump of:

> Distribution ID: Debian
>
> Description: Devian GNU / Linux 10 ( buster )
>
> Release: 10
>
> Codename: Buster

I did not have the current user in the sudoers file, so instead I would just run the entire thing as root, so i just ran the terminal command to update current user to Root.

```
sudo apt install psmisc git rake libvirt-daemon-system dnsmasq-base ebtables qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils vagrant vagrant-libvirt vmdebootstrap && sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```

and then I get the repo, checkout devel and do submodule, but my issues all occur on rake when I am attempting to build everything. When I run:

```
rake build && rake vm:halt
```

But this `rake build` is where the errors end up occurring.

So it looks like it will 'successfully add the box tails-builder-amd64-stretch-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx' (v0) for 'libvert' but then it will bring up the machine 'default' with 'libvert' provider. It will throw the error:

> Error while creating domain: Error saving the server: Call to
>   virDomainDefineXML failed: invalid argument: could not find
>   capabilities for arch=x86_64 domaintype=kvm

It makes me think that it doesnt have KVM, but i am not sure.

Here is an image of my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJwFF.jpg

This image makes me think it is KVM related, but im not sure if maybe Virtualbox needs special permissions for the CPU, or if i need dedicated hardware, or if there is another issue I am unaware of.  I would like to at least get a build running.

Comment: It looks like it expects you to be using KVM and not virtualbox as your virtualization provider based on your error output. Also as far as I know virtualbox itself does not support nested virtualization so you will be unable to run kvm from within your virtualbox guest. I am not familiar with tails' build process but according to your output it expects to be able to spin up a kvm virtual machine as part of the process and in your current setup that will not be possible. You will need to try this process on a Linux host not a Linux guest to confirm this.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the output of the following commads? `grep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` `lsmod | grep 'kvm'` `sudo kvm-ok` If the commands do not work please comment and I will remove this and find more appropriate commands to run. Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep Currently left my machine at home, so i will get an update out later this evening.  If this is in fact the case, while also working on your commands later this evening, I will see about doing a native live debian off of a thumb stick and see if this creates a solution which works

Comment: As a heads up those commands are for checking to see if you Debian instance's cpu has support for virtualization, the kvm kernel module, and if kvm is installed and supported, respectively. I suggest you read through these links that are tangential to your issue to get an idea of what is going wrong. [1](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/539) [2](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/1630) [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/371975/linux-kvm-on-a-virtualbox) [4](https://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/nested-virtualization-with-kvm-intel/) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @kemotep ill keep you in the loop as I get some insight later today. :)

Comment: And if possible correct `vibvert` to `libvirt`...